# Wasserstein GAN problem with last discriminator layer and clipping

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

When I use linear or No activation in the last Discriminator layer using weight clipping Discriminator accuracy goes to 1 and Generator goes to 0. In case when I remove weight clipping, Generator accuracy goes to 1 and discriminator goes to 0 around 300 iterations. But when I use sigmoid activation as the last layer in the discriminator with clipping Generator accuracy goes to 1 and without clipping the generator loss get stuck while accuracies going as they should around 0.5.
NOTE - in all cases, results are produced  and all of the show WARNING:tensorflow:Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights, did you set `model.trainable` without calling `model.compile` after ?

Code is given here, please do not mind the indentation on copying and pasting it's everywhere -

```
class WGAN():

  def  __init__(self, 
              input_dim,
              disc_filter,
              disc_kernel,
              disc_strides,
              disc_dropout,
              disc_lr,
              gen_filter,
              gen_kernel,
              gen_strides,
              gen_upsample,
              gen_lr,
              z_dim,
              batch_size):


      self.input_dim = input_dim
      self.disc_filter = disc_filter
      self.disc_kernel = disc_kernel
      self.disc_strides = disc_strides
      self.disc_dropout = disc_dropout
      self.disc_lr = disc_lr
      self.gen_filter = gen_filter
      self.gen_kernel = gen_kernel
      self.gen_strides = gen_strides
      self.gen_upsample = gen_upsample
      self.gen_lr = gen_lr
      self.z_dim = z_dim
      self.batch_size = batch_size
      self.weight_init = RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=0.02)

      self.d_losses = []
      self.g_losses = []
      self.epoch = 0

      self.Discriminator()
      self.Generator()

      self.full_model()

  def wasserstein(self, y_true, y_pred):
    return -K.mean(y_true * y_pred)

  def Discriminator(self):

    disc_input = Input(shape=self.input_dim, name='discriminator_input')
    x = disc_input

    for i in range(len(self.disc_filter)):
        x = Conv2D(filters=self.disc_filter[i], kernel_size=self.disc_kernel[i], strides=self.disc_strides[i], padding='same', name='disc_'+str(i))(x)
        x = LeakyReLU()(x)
        x = Dropout(self.disc_dropout)(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = Flatten()(x)
    disc_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer = self.weight_init)(x)
    self.discriminator = Model(disc_input, disc_output)

  def Generator(self):

    gen_input = Input(shape=(self.z_dim,), name='generator_input')
    x = gen_input

    x = Dense(7*7*self.batch_size, kernel_initializer = self.weight_init)(x)
    x = LeakyReLU()(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Reshape(target_shape=(7,7,self.batch_size))(x)

    for i in range(len(self.gen_filter)):
        if self.gen_upsample[i]==2:
            x = UpSampling2D(size=self.gen_upsample[i], name='upsample_'+str(i/2))(x)
            x = Conv2D(filters=self.gen_filter[i], kernel_size=self.gen_kernel[i], strides=self.gen_strides[i], padding='same', name='gen_'+str(i))(x)

        else:
            x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=self.gen_filter[i], kernel_size=self.gen_kernel[i], strides=self.gen_strides[i], padding='same', name='gen_'+str(i))(x)

        if i<len(self.gen_filter)-1:
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = LeakyReLU()(x)

        else:
            x = Activation("tanh")(x)

    gen_output = x
    self.generator = Model(gen_input, gen_output)


  def set_trainable(self, model, val):
    model.trainable=val
    for l in model.layers:
        l.trainable=val

  def full_model(self):

    ### COMPILE DISCRIMINATOR
    self.discriminator.compile(optimizer= Adam(self.disc_lr), loss = self.wasserstein, metrics=['accuracy'])

    ### COMPILE THE FULL GAN

    self.set_trainable(self.discriminator, False)
    self.discriminator.compile(optimizer= Adam(self.disc_lr), loss = self.wasserstein, metrics=['accuracy'])

    model_input = Input(shape=(self.z_dim,), name='model_input')
    model_output = self.discriminator(self.generator(model_input))
    self.model = Model(model_input, model_output)

    self.model.compile(optimizer= Adam(self.disc_lr), loss = self.wasserstein, metrics=['accuracy'])

    self.set_trainable(self.discriminator, True)

  def train_generator(self, batch_size):
    valid = np.ones((batch_size,1))
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, self.z_dim))
    return self.model.train_on_batch(noise, valid)

  def train_discriminator(self, x_train, batch_size, using_generator):
    valid = np.ones((batch_size,1))
    fake = np.zeros((batch_size,1))

    if using_generator:
        true_imgs = next(x_train)[0]
        if true_imgs.shape[0] != batch_size:
            true_imgs = next(x_train)[0]
    else:
        idx = np.random.randint(0, x_train.shape[0], batch_size)
        true_imgs = x_train[idx]

    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, self.z_dim))
    gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(noise)

    d_loss_real, d_acc_real =  self.discriminator.train_on_batch(true_imgs, valid)
    d_loss_fake, d_acc_fake =  self.discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, fake)
    d_loss = 0.5 * (d_loss_real + d_loss_fake)
    d_acc = 0.5 * (d_acc_real + d_acc_fake)

    for l in self.discriminator.layers:
        weights = l.get_weights()
        weights = [np.clip(w, -0.01, 0.01) for w in weights]
        l.set_weights(weights)

    return [d_loss, d_loss_real, d_loss_fake, d_acc, d_acc_real, d_acc_fake]

  def train(self, x_train, batch_size, epochs, print_every_n_batches = 50, using_generator = False):

    for epoch in range(self.epoch, self.epoch + epochs):

        d = self.train_discriminator(x_train, batch_size, using_generator)
        g = self.train_generator(batch_size)
        if self.epoch % print_every_n_batches == 0:
            print ("%d [D loss: (%.3f)(R %.3f, F %.3f)] [D acc: (%.3f)(%.3f, %.3f)] [G loss: %.3f] [G acc: %.3f]" % (epoch, d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], g[0], g[1]))

        self.d_losses.append(d)
        self.g_losses.append(g)

        self.epoch+=1
```

---